Unexpected results in fixed-point conversion in Verilog
Why regA and regB have two different values, while regC and regD work as I would expect?
reg signed [31:0] regA;
reg signed [31:0] regB;
reg signed [15:0] regC;
reg signed [15:0] regD;
initial begin
    regA = 0.006 * 2**31;
    regB = 0.006 * (32'b1 << 31);
    regC = 0.006 * 2**15;
    regD = 0.006 * (16'b1 << 15);
    $display("regA = 0x%b, %d", regA, regA);
    $display("regB = 0x%b, %d", regB, regB);
    $display("regC = 0x%b, %d", regC, regC);
    $display("regD = 0x%b, %d", regD, regD);
end

Icarus Verilog returns this
regA = 0x11111111001110110110010001011010,   -12884902
regB = 0x00000000110001001001101110100110,    12884902
regC = 0x0000000011000101,    197
regD = 0x0000000011000101,    197


In the case of regA, you have a signed 32-bit data type that is overflowing and wrapping around to a negative value. The other cases are not overflowing.
When you write a bare numeric literal like 2, you get a signed 32-bit value. With 32'b1 you get an unsigned 32-bit value. So regA/regC are signed 32-bit, regB/regD are unsigned 32-bit. And 2**31 is the point at which the signed 32-bit type will overflow, vs. 2**32 for unsigned 32-bit. So only the regA calculation is overflowing.
Note that all of the integer calculations are happening before the conversion to floating point, so the multiply by 0.006 doesn't come into play here.

It all makes sense, but if I read this my conclusion would be that 2**31 should be made large enough to contain the signed result of 2**31.

I think bare numbers are considered to be self-determined as 32-bit, so not unsized. The rules about auto-extending expression size are complicated so I try not to rely on them too much.
